# EF Core array intersection

Tags: arrays, entity-framework-core, intersection

I use PostgreSQL and have a column `codes` of type `text[]`, and I have another column `filterCodes` of type `string[]`. When I query data from the table, I need to check that `codes` contains at least one element from `filterCodes`, I try use `Intersection` and `Any` but neither seems to work.

How can I do this without writing custom functions?

```
patientQuery.Where(p => p.Codes.Intersect(filterCodes).Any());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation [Array Type Mapping](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) (look at translation of `array1 && array2`)

It should be:

```cs
patientQuery = patientQuery
  .Where(p => p.Codes.Any(c => filterCodes.Contains(c)));
```

Comment: you have typo, `Contains`  :)